# How to tell if a user lands on my site via Google genuinely?

Tags: http, seo, http-headers, e-commerce

It seems to me that checking the Referer in the header is insufficient, because it can be easily spoofed. Are there ways to tell if someone lands on my site from actually searching on Google? Also, are there ways to see the (genuine) keywords used?

Comment: Nope.  Why? What are you trying to do? Why are you afraid of spoofing?

Comment: Because I'm trying to display a slightly different version of my site to visitors genuinely coming from search engines.

Comment: Why are you afraid of spoofing?  Would anything terrible happen if a user lies?

Comment: No, nothing terrible. It'd be better if there's a way to ensure that, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your best option is the Referer header.

Comment: +1, and I guess if it's for SEO purposes, checking the Referer is really good enough anyway.

Comment: No, not quite SEO. I just want to load a different version of my site if the visitor comes from a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

From a statistical view, you can just use Google Analytics to view that data.

Are you trying to use the referrer data in real time?
Are you trying to separate all search engine traffic from other traffic?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to separate out the traffic.

Comment: It's called Google _Analytics_.  And it too uses the `Referer`.